# List files where searched term occurs more than a Threshold

Tags: bash, shell-script, ripgrep

I have a command like

```
rga --files-with-matches --count-matches --sort path -i -e "use cases?" -e "user stor(y|ies)" -e "Technical debt" -e "Code Quality" -e "software development" -e "Agile Manifesto"
```

The output is like

```
a1.pdf:18
a2.pdf:10
a3.pdf:14
....
```

Here, `:NUM` is number of matches.

I want all files who have more than 10 matches (without the colon and number, so that I can pipe the output to another command). Like:

```
a1.pdf
a3.pdf
....
```

I tried `.. | cut -d':' -f2` but it only give the number. `.. | cut -d':' -f1` only gives the file name.

What might be the solution here?

Comment: Edit the question and add the expected output that you want piped to another command. It isn't clear what you are trying to do. You stated that you want `a1.pdf` and `a3.pdf` which is only the file name but then you state that the command that only gives the file name isn't what is wanted.

Comment: The code block after "I want all files who have more tha..." is the expected output. If the number after `:` is more than 10, print the file name (without colon). If you look closely, current output is three files with `:NUM`, the expected output is two files without `:NUM`.

Comment: According to your statement: `.. | cut -d':' -f1 only gives the file name.`, you have that unless there is a misunderstanding. Either way, it's better to edit the question and add what you are actually getting so that it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work even if the filename does contain a `:` character.  It uses two capture groups, the first captures everything up to (but not including) the last `:` character in a line (the filename) and the second capturing all digits after the last `:` (the count).  Input lines not matching that pattern are ignored.

```
$ rga ... | perl -n -E 'm/^(.*):(\d+)$/; say $1 if $2 > 10'
a1.pdf
a3.pdf
```

It won't work on filenames containing newline characters.  If you need that, and `rga` can be made to produce NUL-separated output (e.g. with a `-0` or `-z` or similar option) you could use that in combination with perl's `-0` option for reading NUL-separated input.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
... | awk -F: '$NF>10{ sub(/:[0-9]+$/, ""); print }'
```

Split records on `:` and test if the last field is greater 10. If the condition is true, remove `:` followed by at least one digit at the end of the record. Print the (modified) record.